# Почему deque не принимает нули

Tags: python

Объясните ,пожалуйста, почему при создании q в массиве нет нулей?

```
from collections import deque
def except_zero(items: list):
    q = deque([x for x in sorted(items) if x])
    print(q)
    return [q.popleft() if num else 0 for num in items]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(list(except_zero([5, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 7])))
```

Comment: Потому что `if x` стоит, который их и отсекает

Comment: @dim0n, объясните пожалуйста, если написано просто if x, что это значит? надпись if x эквивалентна надписи if x != 0?

Comment: @Alealan `if x` эквивалентна `if bool(x) == True`. Для чисел `bool(0) = False`, `bool(не 0) = True`, так что да, для чисел эти записи эквивалентны

Answer (score 1):

При `x` равном 0 выражение `if x` является *falsy*, т.е. возвращает значение `False`, поэтому все нулевые значения оказались отфильтрованы. Удалите эту проверку, если нулевые значения необходимы в результате.

См. [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> По умолчанию объект считается истинным, если его класс не определяет метод `__bool__`, возвращающий для объекта `False`, или метод `__len__`, возвращающий для него ноль.

**Объекты, которые приравниваются к `False`**

- Пустой список: `[]`
- Пустой кортеж: `()`
- Пустой словарь: `{}`
- Пустое множество: `set()`
- Пустая строка: `""`
- Пустой диапазон: `range(0)`
- Нули любых численных типов
- Целочисленный ноль: `0`
- Ноль с плавающей точкой: `0.0`
- Комплексный ноль: `0j`
- `None`
- `False`